# How to set start day time to particular time in momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to set the start time of the day to a particular time. currently, in momentjs, I can get startOf day like this

```
 let now = moment()
 console.log('now', now.toString()) 
 console.log('start Day', now.startOf('day').toString()) // Thu Oct 07 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530
 console.log('end day', now.endOf('day').toString()) //Thu Oct 07 2021 23:59:59 GMT+0530
```

is there any way so I can set my day start from particular time like I want to start my day from

> Thu Oct 07 2021 08:00:00 GMT+0530

and end on

> Thu Oct 07 2021 07:59:59 GMT+0530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably write your own function in order to achieve this.

```js
function customStartOf(momentObj) {
  return momentObj.clone().startOf('day').hours(8);
}

function customEndOf(momentObj) {
  // I assume that end of the day is bigger than start of the day
  return momentObj.clone().endOf('day').add(1, 'days').hours(7);
}

let now = moment();

console.log('now', now.toString()) ;
console.log('start Day', now.startOf('day').toString());
console.log('end day', now.endOf('day').toString());

console.log('custom start Day', customStartOf(now).toString());
console.log('custom end day', customEndOf(now).toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want difference  between "Thu Oct 07 2021 08:00:00 GMT+0530" to "Fri Oct 08 2021 08:00:00 GMT+0530" == 1 , but I did get this by your logic any idea how to achieve this

Comment: I want to calculate the date difference between two days based upon "startOf day"

Comment: also `console.log('now', now.toString()) ;` print the same value like this one printed `console.log('custom end day', customEndOf(now).toString());`

Comment: @ManjeetThakur I edited my answer. Custom functions now return cloned objects so, `add` function won't change custom function results.

Comment: but console.log('custom start Day', customStartOf(now).startOf('day').toString()) still print the `Thu Oct 07 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530`

Comment: You don't need to use `startOf`with `customStartOf`, the function already gives you the desired start of the day.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account the timezone.

```
let myDate = new Date();

const timezoneOffset = moment(myDate).utcOffset();

moment(myDate).utc().add(timezoneOffset, 'minutes').startOf('day').format();
moment(myDate).utc().add(timezoneOffset, 'minutes').endOf('day').format();
```